# Small Stakes NLH 1-2 $300 Cap - What did villain have?

Tags: nlhe, live, reading-hands

This is a newly formed $300 max $1-$2 No-Limit 10 man live game. I am in the small blind with:

8♥ 7♥

It goes fold, fold, limp, limp, raise to $12(villain), call, call, I call, $11, fold, and first to limpers fold.

So there are 5 players with $62 in pot.

Flop comes:

A♥ 2♥ 9♥

I check to the preflop raiser with the intent to checkraise get clarity on the strength of my flush hoping to get all folds. He bets $50 (this is a larger size bet for this table), everyone folds to me. I checkraised to get a true feeling of where I am in this pot, I min raise to $100. I started the hand with $350 and villain had roughly $280. The villain hesitated and calls only. The turn cards is:

A♥ 2♥ 9♥ A♠

I jam the pot all-in; the villain has $160+ left. He thinks for about a half of minute and calls. I table my made flush, and he holds his cards, the river came with what I thought was the worst possible cards for what I had put the villain on. It was the:

A♥ 2♥ 9♥ A♠ A♣

The whole table including myself groan. I say verbally under my breath, "That was a bad card." The villain stares then says, "You are good." and mucks his hand.

I took me a bit but I did finally put him on one type of hand.

What do you think he had?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect he had KH-QX or KH-JX or KH-TX.

I don't think it makes much sense for him to raise preflop with 3H 4H or 5H 6H.  And, he would play KH-8X or less raising preflop.

And, since he didn't win the had, he didn't pair the board nor have a pocket pair.

Comment: KQ or a pair is about the only hands that would make sense with his pre flop raise. KJ, KX and less, although possible, a little to aggressive in a new game.  King of hearts in his hand. His large bet is to discourage others from drawing and making pairs and possibly to take OP off smaller flush. Like Scott said more or less, upvoted.

Comment: After discussing this a bit with a friend of mine, if the villain is a very good player, you could rule out KH offsuit also.  A very good player would re-raise you flop check raise with the KH as a blocker in his hand representing he also made a flush with the KH.  So, the villian in this situation  has QH offsuit connector.

Comment: QJ seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you, I think a high heart is most likely. Kh-x maybe even Qh-x, depending on how maniacal he is he could have something like 3h4h, 3h5h, or 4h5h, as well, although these are not the type of hands people normally raise with.

Comment: I had a friend agree with you QH-x holding also, with that the most likely hand.  See comment in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is, he misread his hand.

There is no hand which V can correctly call your turn push that doesn't win on the river.

if V had lower flush (3-6h), to me this is a standard flop jam over your reraise. Theres really no good way to play a bluff (low suited connector) that has connected so well with the flop.

For KhXx, QhXx, there aren't that many combinations i would open (KQo, KJo, QJo), and looking at a turn push, i have no equity to call, as i may not even have 9 outs (sets + made boats, plus higher flush for QhXx).

My impression is Villain had high pocket with a heart, figured he had 9 outs plus 2 if he made his set, and forgot about the third Ace giving him the boat.

Comment: LOL... now that is an interesting read on this hand.  Maybe so.  Thank you for your imput.  +1